# Visitor Pattern/Leaky Bucket variant implementation to run an operation at a certain interval

Tags: c#, timer, async-await, visitor-pattern

My code is a variant on the Visitor Pattern and a "leaky bucket" variant. The goal is pretty straightforward: the "bucket" will collect a specified number of items (say, for example, 500) and then empty the queue, running some CPU-bound operation on ("visiting") each item. (Yes, I'm aware that there's probably existing code "out there" that does something similar to what I'm doing here - this code really isn't all *that* novel of an idea).

I've read documentation on how to implement the Visitor pattern before but this is truthfully the first time I've actually implemented one. Is what I have below a "valid" way to implement this? Also, have I properly implemented the concurrency/thread safety? I think it should be free from race conditions but it's also possible that I can implement this more simply.

```
/// <summary>
/// "Overflowing bucket" implementation
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the data structure we're operating on</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="U">Type of the items in the data structure</typeparam>
/// <remarks>
/// The basic idea of this data structure is that it'll collect a certain number of items and then empty the queue.
/// 
/// The "overflowing bucket" metaphor isn't perfect because every time that the "bucket" is "filled to the brim" or starts
/// to "overflow" we just empty the whole thing.
/// </remarks>
public class OverflowingBucket<T, U>
{
    #region Fields
    // Not volatile - this will only be accessed by the background thread
    private readonly T itemToActOn;

    // Not volatile - this will only be accessed by the background thread
    private readonly Action<T, U> visitorOperation;

    // This action runs after we empty the queue
    private readonly Action<T> afterAction;

    // Must be concurrent because we could add to the queue while an operation is in place
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<U> queue;

    // Will be accessed by multiple threads
    private volatile bool inProgress = false;

    // Obviously used for locking
    private readonly object lockObj = new object();
    #endregion Fields

    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new Overflowing Bucket
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="itemToActOn">Item that is "visited." Required.</param>
    /// <param name="visitorOperation">Visitor operation. Required.</param>
    /// <param name="afterAction">Action that occurs after each time that the queue is emptied. Optional.</param>
    /// <param name="leakyNumber">Number of items that the queue may contain before the bucket starts "leaking."</param>
    public OverflowingBucket(T itemToActOn, Action<T, U> visitorOperation, Action<T> afterAction, int leakyNumber = 50)
    {
        this.itemToActOn = itemToActOn;
        this.visitorOperation = visitorOperation;
        this.afterAction = afterAction;
        queue = new ConcurrentQueue<U>();
        LeakyNumber = leakyNumber;
    }
    #endregion Constructor

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set the number at which we run an iteration
    /// </summary>
    public int LeakyNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a value indicating whether a "visit" is already in progress (i.e. we are actively emptying the queue)
    /// </summary>
    public bool InProgress
    {
        get { return inProgress; }
    }
    #endregion Properties

    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Add an item, emptying the queue if necessary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Item to add to the "bucket"</param>
    /// <returns>Handle to await the outcome</returns>
    public async Task Add(U item)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);

        if (queue.Count >= LeakyNumber && !inProgress)
        {
            await Visit();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Visit the data structure. This will ignore successive calls (i.e. calls that occur while a previous"visit" operation is running).
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Handle to await the boolean result; result is <c>true</c> if we successfully ran the
    /// operation and <c>false</c> if the operation failed or never ran</returns>
    public async Task<bool> Visit()
    {
        // If there's already an operation in progress, ignore the call
        if (!inProgress)
        {
            bool result = true;
            await Task.Run(
                delegate ()
                {
                    lock (lockObj)
                    {
                        // "Double check" pattern to prevent race conditions
                        if (!inProgress)
                        {
                            inProgress = true;

                            // Completely empty the queue
                            while (queue.Any())
                            {
                                U item;

                                bool success = queue.TryDequeue(out item);

                                if (success) visitorOperation(itemToActOn, item);
                                else result = false;
                            }

                            // The "afterAction" operation is optional, so only
                            afterAction?.Invoke(itemToActOn);

                            inProgress = false;
                        } // End double-check condition
                    } // Release lock
                }); // End Task

            return result;
        } // End if inProgress

        // TODO: Should we throw an exception if we're already Visiting?
        return false;
    } // End Visit method
    #endregion Public Methods
} // End OverflowingBucket class
```

Here is an example of code that I wrote to call this (to give a better sense of what I'm trying to do).

It's probably not that great of an example because the operations in question aren't particularly CPU-bound (which is obviously the primary purpose of Task.Run operations), but it should still give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
private static void TestOverflowingBucket()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<QATestLog></QATestLog>");

        Action<XmlDocument, XmlElement> operation =
            delegate (XmlDocument document, XmlElement element)
            {
                document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);
            };

        Action<XmlDocument> afterOperation = xmlDoc => xmlDoc.Save("TestDocument.xml");

        var bucket = new OverflowingBucket<XmlDocument, XmlElement>(doc, operation, afterOperation);

        // AsyncPump is to correct some "oddities" in the way that async/await works in a console application
        // Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/
        AsyncPump.Run(async () =>
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1003; i++)
            {
                XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement("step");

                XmlAttribute newAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("number");
                newAttribute.Value = i.ToString();

                newElement.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);

                // Don't await, it's OK for us to continue to add to the queue while an execution is happening
                // This will generate a compiler warning since Add is async and we don't await
                Task task = bucket.Add(newElement);

                // For added realism, wait some random time between adds
                await Task.Delay(random.Next(1, 1000));

                if (!task.IsCompleted)
                    tasks.Add(task);
            }

            if (bucket.InProgress)
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                // If there are any "left over" that weren't "picked up" by a previous Visit execution
                await bucket.Visit();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, IMHO the code is well written and has some meaningful comments.

**Visitor Pattern**

Actually, I am not sure if the `OverflowingBucket` has something to do with the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). In my eyes, the visitor pattern can be used to add logic to a data structure by implementing visitors. A visitor visits each element of the data structure and decide what to do depending of the element's type.

The `OverflowingBucket` can be used to add logic to an object for processing other items in a special manner. Therfore I wouldn't use the term "visitor pattern" here.

**OverflowingBucket**

- Because it is not a visitor in my eyes, I would rename the method `Visit` 
  to `Process` or something like that.
- Consider to make the method `Process` private and add another method `ProcessPendingItems` or something like that.
- The only case where the method `Visit` returns false is, if `queue.Any()` is true and `queue.TryDequeue(out item)` is false. That should never happen in the current version of the class... therefore I would make the method void.

**TestOverflowingBucket**

- The delay does not delay the Add-Task but the main thread. Adding `Thread.Sleep()` within the operation delegate would be more realistic.
- There is no need to check if the task is completed. You can just add them all to the `tasks` list.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer simplicity when it comes to `async/await`. `await` is useful and makes the code cleaner when you have code that executes after a `Task` completes. Using it just to pass tasks along methods (like in `public async Task Add(U item)`), creates noise.

In `public async Task<bool> Visit()` you only use `await` to wait for the task to finish so that you can return it's result. I would have rather made the delegate return a `bool` rather then capture `result` and modifying it and then I would have simply returned the task created by `Task.Run` or `Task.FromResult` in the case of your other branch.

Answer (score 0):

I largely agree with JanDotNet.

I'm not sure if it's a good idea, but maybe `OverflowingBucket` should clean up after it self as a IDisposable?